# Magento. buy product from any of specified categories, and buy product from specified category for special price

Tags: magento

I am new to magento platform, but the project that i am working on is pretty hard. One of the tasks that i have to accomplish it the following.

lets assume i have 3 categories with products in them. category A, category B, category C.

```
if someone buys any product from category A or B then:
    2 products from category C should have different prices (special prices)
```

I am assuming that this have to do with Shopping cart price rule

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Shopping Cart Price Rules.

1. Go to **Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules**
2. Click **Add New Promotion**
3. Fill out the Rule Name, select the Customer Groups
4. On the **Conditions** Tab, set it up as follows (using Category A and B for the category ids)

   [image: Shopping Cart Price Rules: Conditions Tab]
5. On the **Actions** tab, set it up as follows (Using Category B for the category id)
   [image: Shopping Cart Price Rules: Actions Tab]

This rule will discount Category C products by 10%, if a product from Category A or Category B are present in the shopping cart.

Comment: Worked Greatly. Thank you.